# Problemas con una consulta laravel al comparar

Tags: laravel

Quiero comparar los datos el problema que no se si mi sintaxis esta buena al quitar el and 'ano', si me compara bien pero al comparar ya con 2 no me esta funcionando la consulta no se si es la sintaxis por que no me tira ningun error

```
 public static function unidades_dinamico($id){

        return   \DB::table('organizador_tareas')
            ->join('unidades','unidades.id', '=', 
                   'organizador_tareas.unidad')
            ->join('anos_trabajo','anos_trabajo.id', '=', 
                   'organizador_tareas.ano')
            ->groupBy('id','unidad')
            ->select('unidades.id','unidades.unidad')->where('gerencia' and 
                     'ano','=',$id)
            ->get();
//           
    }
```

Comment: así como esta no le veo lógica, pues le estas diciendo que procese y muestre resultados donde generencia y ano sean igual al id, seguro que si haces eso en sql puro funciona? generencia y id van a coincidir con los datos que llegan en la variable id?

Comment: deberías estar usando 2 veces el método `where` el primero para comparar gerencia y el segundo para comparar ano

Comment: bueno es que la consulta tiene que ser algo asi  que me traiga el id y la unidad cuando  este este en el mismo ano y en la misma gerencia

Comment: por eso mi último comentario, necesitas un where para gerencia y otro para ano

Comment: puede obtener una imagen del modelo entidad relación para entender mejor la pregunta y si es posible coloque el archivo sql

Answer (score 0):

En SQL pondrías algo similar a esto

```
WHERE(gerencia = "valorUno" AND ano = 2018);
```

Mientras que para lograr algo similar en Laravel deberás ocupar dos veces el método `where`

```
->where('gerencia', '=', $gerencia)
->where('ano', '=', $ano)
```

O bien puedes hacerlo de este modo, con un solo `where` mediante un array para indicar múltples condiciones

```
->where([
    ['gerencia', '=', $gerencia],
    ['ano', '=', $ano],
])
```